# jQuery datatable headers are not taking full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am rendering a jQuery datatable via ng-repeat in Angular JS. The table is inside a bootstrap tab(which is primarily hidden) and also inside a bootstrap accordion. Now my table body is taking full width but the table headers are not taking full width and are gathered in left side.
I have called the **column.adjust()** function on tab change but no result.
Is it a bug in jQuery Datatable? Or can you please help me where am I doing wrong.

On tab change;

```
$('#toptab').on('click', function (e) {

    for(var i=0;i<$scope.grids.length;i++)
        $scope.grids[i].columns.adjust().draw();

});
```

Filling the datatable with data

```
setTimeout(function() {
    table = $("#xl_" + key).DataTable({
        "aaData": tableBody,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'],
        //"scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": true,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [100, 250, 500, -1],
            [100, 250, 500, "All"]
        ],
    })
    $scope.grids.push(table);
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Your table is hidden initially which prevents jQuery DataTables from adjusting column widths.

#### SOLUTION

If table is in the collapsible element, you need to adjust headers when collapsible element becomes visible.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();
});
```

If table is in the tab, you need to adjust headers when tab becomes visible.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();
});
```

Code above adjusts column widths for all tables on the page.

See [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods for more information.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solutions to the most common problems with columns in jQuery DataTables when table is initially hidden.

Comment: This solution worked well...second solution to for my case since the table inside tab.. Thanks :)